# Graphical ssh private key prompt not showing up

Tags: ssh

I recently stopped using a full desktop environment in ubuntu 11.10 (tired of unity) but I'm trying to get some of the desktop environment back. I'm currently trying to get the "Unlock private key" dialog to show up when I'm trying to use a new ssh key. However, currently the prompt only shows up in the terminal window instead of the gui, which means that it isn't using a global ssh-agent and hence I need to enter the key password multiple times before I restart.

I think what I want is gnome-ssh-askpass and I tried setting SSH_ASKPASS but that didn't work:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-replace-ssh-askpass-with-ssh-askpass-gnome-843220/

I've also tried gnome-keyring-daemon as gnome-keyring-daemon --components keyring,pkcs11,ssh but that didn't help:
http://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring/Ssh

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I would love to hear.

Comment: Sorry, don't remember what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're really looking for is [keychain](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/QuickTips#Tip_.233_Keychain_-_Manage_ssh_keys), which is similar to the `ssh-reagent` you mention. Once configured in your `.bashrc` it'll prompt for the passphrase of the key(s) you asked it to manage only when you launch the *first* terminal after login and makes sure every new terminal knows about your `ssh-agent`.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the issue of entering the password multiple times, enter this command the first
time you open a terminal:
ssh-add

---

No need to enter the password until you log out.

Comment: I don't really like that solution because it's irritating doing that for every new terminal window (I tend to make many windows). I currently use ssh-reagent http://pastebin.com/HBeUzZhs but even doing that in every window is irritating so I might add it to my .zshrc

Comment: No need to do it for every window, once is enough.

Answer (score 1):

It should be automatic if you've set up the ssh key on both systems.  With a default installation, I've never had to do anything else.

In case you haven't done this, here is the way it's done:

Generate the key (either RSA or DSA).  I think RSA is more common.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

or

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

Transfer the key to the remote system:

```
ssh-copy-id *username* @ *hostname*
```

If not using the standard port 22:  (note quotes are required around argument)

```
ssh-copy-id *username* @ *hostname* -p *portnum*"
```

If using DSA, you need to use a something like:

```
ssh-copy-id -i *path*  *to*   id_dsa
```

Once I've done that, I get the dialog.  In the past, I  remember that if I ran the terminal in a certain way, it wouldn't give the dialog, but I can't remember the details.  I think it was when I created a hotkey for a custom command to set the directory due to a bug where the terminal kept coming up in the root directory even though it knew my home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've added this as a new answer because I didn't want it to get last in my other answer.

I have found that if you start gnome-terminal, or xterm or other terminals (I believe) from a custom hotkey rather than the built in hotkey or menu, then it behaves totally differently for SSH, and will not use the keyring.  In fact, when I just tried it on my system after remembering this problem, I actually got an error, where it always works from the default methods.

Comment: This might be related since I am using Awesome WM's Super+Enter shortcut to launch the terminal.

Comment: Do you run Awesome with Gnome?  If so, maybe you can get the SSH working with the standard WM first, then if that works, you'll know where to look for solutions.

Comment: It was working fine before I switched to AwesomeWM

Comment: Well, wish I could help further.  I tried taking a look at Awesome once, but never got far, and didn't feel like spending a lot of time figuring it out.  It looks like it might be interesting, but I don't know that it really does anything I can't do with Compiz, except maybe using less resources.

Answer (score 0):

If gnome's gui doesn't prompt you for the password it could mean that `gnome-keyring-d` is not running
or it is in an invalid state.
I would check if the process is running:

```
ps -e | grep gnome-keyring-d
```

If it is then kill it:

```
killall -9 gnome-keyring-d
```

Then restart it

```
gnome-keyring-daemon
```

After that when I do `ssh <remotehost>` I get the gui prompt and the `ssh-agent` under the hood doing
it's job.